# How can I change the default datasheet font in MS Access 2010?

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I've never liked the default font that is used as for datasheet views in MS Access.  Recently, I've upgraded from 2003 to 2010, and for the life of me I can not find out how (via Google or otherwise) to change the default font that is used for displaying data in tables or queries.

I'm not looking for a way to set the font on a form.  I want to change the default font that is used to display any data, in datasheet view.

FYI, I assume this may involve registry hack and I wouldn't mind that approach.  Does anyone know if this setting can be changed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open RegEdit and go to this location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Settings
```

I added a new string value named "Default Font Name" (without the quotes) and entered a value of "Arial" (no quotes).  No re-boot is needed.

Open any existing Access file and the font will be changed in the datasheet view.  Note: If you already have access running then close and re-open Access.

Comment: This isn't the answer because this options only changes the settings of the font (i.e. size, weight, etc.) but not the font itself.  In my case, I prefer fixed-width fonts (like consolas) to be the font for all of my data views.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I have the answer and will edit my answer.

Comment: Bingo!  Wow, seems easy enough but how did you figure this one out?  I couldn't find this solution any where in the web and it's quite simple.  Thanks a ton!

Comment: Oh, it's also worth mentioning that no reboot "of the PC" is necessary.  I still needed to close Access (I had a few DB and numerous tables/queries opened this morning) for this change to take affect.  But, that type of behavior isn't unexpected.

Comment: This worked great but I had to change 14.0 to 16.0 for Access 2016 (O365).  I'm working with a Japanese client and somehow my datasheets started showing with a Japanese friendly font but it didn't have ClearType so it was annoying.  I changed my default font to `Calibri`.

Answer (score 2):

Open a form or report in design view so you can get access to the *Themes* tab. Change the *Fonts* setting to your choice of fonts. This will change the default font for not only reports and forms but also datasheet views (queries or tables).

Answer (score -2):

On the ribbon, click *Home*. On the sixth tab, labelled *Text Formatting*, the first box has the font name and font size.

Change this and everything resizes in the datasheet view.

Comment: This does not change the default font, just for this one datasheet.